# How to count the values inside the array

Tags: php, arrays, count

i have exploded the line:

```
$e_line = explode(" ", $lineDetails2[0]);
```

and when i use this code: ' print_r($e_line); ' this will display this:

```
Array ( [0] => S1 [1] => T5000 [2] => IR [3] => 0.110796 [4] => V [5] => 0.000 [6] => 5.000 ) 7
```

and the other one is:

Array ( [0] => TestInfo ) 1 .

i would like to count the value of that array. I used ' count($e_line); ' and this return the value of 7 for the first array and 1 for the second array. but, when i use a condition '

```
if(count($e_line == 1){ echo $e_line[0] ',
```

both array will display. 
I want to display only the 'TestInfo' but 'S1' will display too. Please help. THANKS in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `count()` on a scalar value will always return 1, in this case it's the boolean expression `$e_line == 1`. This behaviour is also described in the [manual](http://php.net/count#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues).

You should take the comparison outside of the braces, so instead of:

```
if (count($e_line == 1)) { ... }
```

You should write:

```
if (count($e_line) == 1) { ... }
```

This compares the number of elements in `$e_line` against `1`.